# Displaying image as image gallery using PHP derived from phpmyadmin(MySQL)

Tags: php, html, mysql, image, display

I am using PHP, HTML, and MySQL to build a website.

So, my goal is to make an image gallery for my webpage which should display only 3 images each row.

But my code seems wrong and I do not know where should I do the correction.

**-) Here is my code:**

```
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products WHERE catID = 11 ORDER BY typeID ASC"); 

echo "<table>";

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) 
{

echo "<tr>";

    for ($c = 0; $c < 3; $c += 1){

      echo "<td>";

        echo    '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['productImg'] ).'" width="300" height="200" alt=""
             />';

        echo    "<br>";

            echo "<b>";
        echo    $row['productName'];
            echo "</b>";

        echo    "<br>";

        // More detail button set up
        ?><a href="show.php?productID=<?php echo $row["productID"]; ?>">More Detail <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></a> <?php



      echo "</td>";
    }

 echo "</tr>";

}

 echo "</table>";
```

-) Here is the result:
[wrong result image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUjUK.png)

The result turns out not what I expected since on 1 row it displays 3 same images. What I wanted is to display 3 different images on each
 row. I do not know where I did wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The result turns out not what I expected since on 1 row it displays 3 same images.

That's because of the `for` loop, you are looping through the same image three times. Instead use a counter variable `$counter` to track number of iterations and display three different images per row.

```
<?php
    $query = mysql_query("SELECT DISTINCT * FROM products WHERE catID = 11 ORDER BY typeID ASC"); 

    if(mysql_num_rows($query)){
        $counter = 0;
        echo "<table><tr>";
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
            if($counter != 0 && $counter % 3 == 0){
                echo "</tr><tr>";
            }
            echo "<td>";
                echo '<img src="data:image/jpg;base64,'.base64_encode($row['productImg'] ).'" width="300" height="200" alt=""/>';
                echo "<br>";
                echo "<b>";
                echo $row['productName'];
                echo "</b>";
                echo "<br>";
                // More detail button set up
                ?>
                <a href="show.php?productID=<?php echo $row["productID"]; ?>">More Detail <i class="fa fa-arrow-circle-o-right"></i></a> 
                <?php
            echo "</td>";
            ++$counter;
        }
        echo "</tr></table>";
    }
?>
```

---

**Sidenote:** Don't use `mysql_*` functions, they are deprecated as of PHP 5.5 and are removed altogether in PHP 7.0. Use [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`pdo`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead. [And this is why you shouldn't use `mysql_*` functions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php).

Comment: Thanks! Because of university purpose somehow I am sticking with PHP v5.5.
Your code working fine but, I found out an issue that the $counter is better to be assign with 0 value or else the arrangement will be weird (1st row showing 3 images, but the following row displaying 4 images). 

But no worries, the code working fine! Thanks again...

Comment: @Json, Thanks for raising the issue, I have initialised `$counter` to `0` and changed the `if` condition accordingly, now it should work fine.